# RStudio and Travis CI build check do NOT match (libudunits2.so)

Tags: github, build, rstudio, travis-ci, units-of-measurement

Travis CI detects and issue which is not found by the `Build > Check` in `RStudio` for my `lares` library (found in Github as laresbernardo/lares). My last "Passed" commit, according to Travis CI, was literally a typo change so the library's code should not be the problem; so, when I run `devtools::check()` for the library, I get the nice `R CMD check succeeded` message with 0 errors, warnings, or notes.

I've tried what the messages suggest and other stuff too:

- Run `brew install udunits` in Terminal (macOS)
- Install the library via CRAN with `install.packages(units)`
- and via Github (dev) with `devtools::install_github("r-quantities/units", args="--configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'")`
- and `devtools::install_github("r-quantities/units", args="--configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'")`

This is the end of the Travis CI log, also found here: https://travis-ci.org/laresbernardo/lares

```
(...)
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpITNXhh/R.INSTALL3d3b9a0f951/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/home/travis/R/Library/units’
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
Calls: <Anonymous> ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
Execution halted
The command "Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

I am out of ideas. Is it a change in `stringi` or `units` libraries? Or a Travis CI issue? Or something in my library set differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved adding the following to the `.travis.yml` file! Me must specify that this library needs to be installed.

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libudunits2-dev
```

Thanks to Iñaki Ucar, developer of the `units` library, for the very useful answer.

Comment: Can you expand on where this section needs to added to the `.travis.yml` file. Currently, my file is just: 
`language: R
cache: packages`

Comment: Anywhere really.. just below that line would be fine @ChintanPathak